# .htaccess doesn't work in WampServer 2.5

Tags: .htaccess, wampserver

I have got a problem with `.htaccess` in WampServer 2.5.

I use Windows 10 Enterprise and have installed `wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-64b_August_2015` on it.

Every thing is going well except .htaccess configs. 
I want `.php` extention removed from website url like (www.mywebsite.com/contact.php) should look like (www.mywebsite.com/contact), but it doesn't work and displays (404 Not Found error).

The URLs link is like:

```
<a href="contact">link</a>
```

But when adding .php extention at the link :

```
<a href="contact.php">link</a>
```

it works.

I use this bunch of codes in my .htaccess :

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
  # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
  # RewriteBase /
</IfModule>
```

I also tried some other codes like above, but no results.
Previously in windows 8.1 and wampserver2.2 it was waroking, but now in wamp2.5 it puts me in trouble.
how should i get it solved?

Comment: Long shot here, but do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled in apache?

Comment: Yes its solved and working now. I enabled  "rewrite_module" of Apache.
It was not up before.

Comment: I've added it as an answer, just so this question can me marked as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this youtube step by step tutorial related to enable rewrite module in wamp apache
https://youtu.be/xIspOX9FuVU?t=1m43s
Wamp server icon -> Apache -> Apache Modules and check the rewrite module option

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to remember is correctly coded .htaccess files work just fine.

The first thing to check is that you have enabled the `rewrite_module` in Apache. Without this module activated `.htaccess` files are ignored.

To check and enable this module use the WAMPManager menu like so:

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Module
```

This should show you a menu with all the available apache modules, there are many you will have to scroll the menu down to `rewrite_module`, if there is a TICK beside this module it is enabled already, if there is no TICK, then click on the `rewrite_module` menu item and it will amend the `httpd.conf` file automatically and restart Apache for you.

Then try you site again.

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly, I did not enable rewrite_module of Apache,
now have enabled it and problem is solved.