# .htaccess doesnt work with warmserver 2.5

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have similar issue with [.htaccess doesn't work in WampServer 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231857/htaccess-doesnt-work-in-wampserver-2-5)

However even if I enable apache rewrite_module, it still not working.

.htaccess file is working perfectly with my older version warmserver 2.0 .. And when I update to 2.5, it show up like a mess.

What am I suppose to fix this?

Comment: You should make sure that `AllowOverride all` is set in your `httpd.conf` as well, otherwise .htaccess files may be ignored. Check out the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) for more on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

Found the answer from this.